# Another way of saying that 'the effect of A to B is double-edged'?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, idioms

I am writing an essay describing the effect of water to aerosol scattering coefficients.

Water will increase the size of particles, thus increase scattering coefficients; while it may also reduce the refractive index which could decrease scattering coefficients. I want to summarize this phenomenon as:

> The effect of water to aerosol scattering coefficients is **dual-edged**.

I am not sure whether the word 'dual-edged' is used correctly and particularly looking for a properer replacement.

What would be a nicer way of saying this?

Comment: I would say that it has *two opposing effects* - opposing because they push in opposite directions.  Eg, *"Water has two opposing effects on aerosol scattering coefficients"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Water can have **two opposite effects** on aerosol scattering coefficient. While it increases the size...

Water has two different effects on aerosol scattering coefficient, and they **are antagonistic**.  While  it...

> - [**antagonistic**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/antagonistic) -  mutually opposed, acting in opposition; opposing, esp. mutually.

You could also say that water **"has a dual effect"**

Answer (score 1):

The effect of water to aerosol scattering coefficients is **twofold**.

> ADJECTIVE Having two parts or elements

-[ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twofold)